# Copying files in a directory to a docker container not at same level as Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am trying to copy content of a directory while creating the docker image in the Dockerfile but while copying its giving me error-

> COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder108255131/Users/user_1/media : no
>   such file or directory

I have the following file in the Dockerfile-

```
COPY /Users/user_1/media/. /code/project_media/
```

The media directory is in a seperate directory level then Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry per dockerfile documentation:

> Multiple  resources may be specified but the paths of files and directories will be interpreted as relative to the source of the context of the build

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

I usually will have a script for building the docker, and in that script will copy the files need for the `COPY` command into either the same directory or sub-directory of the "context of the build" (a very confusing way of saying the same directory as the dockerfile is in)

```
DOCKER_BUILD_DIR="./build/docker"
DOCKERFILE="./docker/Dockerfile"
MEDIA_FILES="/Users/user_1/media"

mkdir -p "${DOCKER_BUILD_DIR}/${MEDIA_FILES}"
cp -f "${DOCKERFILE}" "${DOCKER_BUILD_DIR}/"
cp -rf "${MEDIA_FILES}" "${DOCKER_BUILD_DIR}/${MEDIA_FILES}/.."

docker build "${DOCKER_BUILD_DIR}"
```

Comment: More succinctly: anything that gets `COPY`d into a Docker image must be in the same directory tree as the `Dockerfile`.  You cannot `COPY` from an arbitrary place on disk.

Comment: The "Context of the Build" makes perfect sense if you look at the `docker build` command.  The command is `docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -` where `PATH | URL | -` is your "Context of the Build."  If you are just looking at the "Dockerfile" reference, then it is confusing to me...